# Angular 2 CLI project; when I change and save something in child component which is in a subdirectory, live server does not reload the page

Tags: angularjs, angular2-cli

**Angular2 CLI** project; Using **Linux** machine; **Atom** IDE

NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200,

When I change and save something in root or app component, server automatically detect the changes and reload the page and shows the effect of changes done in root component.

But when I change and save something in a **child component** which is only in a **sub-directory** of app directory, angular2 does not detect the changes or app does not reload.

Then I stop the server or app running (with ctrl c)and then `run ng` serve again to see the effect of changes. So each time I change or do something with child component , I do this unexpected work.

In Terminal, it does not complain about any error.

Anyone please help me, what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to inotify and I followed the instruction in the following links and restarted my computer, it works.

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2082

https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md#typeerror-unable-to-watch-path